# Troubles with c Syntax - const * const * definition

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, parameters, constants

I have troubles using a function that is defined like this:

```
some_function(address_t const * const * my_addrs, uint8_t length)
```

wheareas address_t is defined as:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t addr_id   : 1;       
  uint8_t addr_type : 7;       
  uint8_t addr[6]; 
} address_t;
```

How am I supposed to call this function?

The code is from a bluetooth library and is supposed to set a whitelist of bluetooth addresses. So the idea is to define multible address_t structs with different addr[6] information.

Thank you very much for any help

edit: here are some more information

I have several addres_t structs. They are defined like this:

```
address_t addr1 = {.addr_id= 1, .addr_type = 3, .addr = {0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0x90,0xAB}};
address_t addr2 = ...
```

I can combine then to an array like:

```
address_t my_whitelist[6];
my_whitelist[0] = addr1;
my_whitelist[1] = addr2;
...
```

I'm not sure if this is needed or not. Now I have to pass this some how to this function. I hope this further information helps.

Comment: *How am I supposed to call this function?* what do you want to want to call it on? Do you have an array of `address_t` or do you an array of array or array of `address_t` or just a `address_t`. How are we supposed to answer anything without knowing this?

Comment: Is `some_function` supposed to allocate memory for `*my_addrs`?

Comment: Ok so you are saying that both the definition of `some function` and the definition of the `struct` are correct and should not be modified.....

Comment: yes the some_function and the struct are given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How am I supposed to call this function?

Example call

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t addr_id :1;
  uint8_t addr_type :7;
  uint8_t addr[6];
} address_t;

//                      1st const,  2nd const
//                          v---v   v---v
int some_function(address_t const * const * my_addrs, uint8_t length) {
  (void) my_addrs;
  (void) length;
  return 0;
}

int foo() {
  const address_t addr1 = { .addr_id = 1, .addr_type = 3, .addr = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 } };
  const address_t addr2 = { .addr_id = 1, .addr_type = 3, .addr = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 } };
  const address_t addr3 = { .addr_id = 1, .addr_type = 3, .addr = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 } };
```

Notice the type change of `my_whitelist[]`.  This need to be an array of pointers.  Those pointers need to point to `const` data due to `1st const` above.

```
  // address_t my_whitelist[6];
  const address_t *my_whitelist[6];
  my_whitelist[0] = &addr1;
  my_whitelist[1] = &addr2;
  my_whitelist[2] = &addr3;
  my_whitelist[3] = &addr1;
  my_whitelist[4] = &addr2;
  my_whitelist[5] = &addr1;
  uint8_t len = sizeof my_whitelist / sizeof my_whitelist[0];
```

Notice `my_whitelist[]` does *not* need to be `const` due to the `2nd const` above as with `const address_t * const my_whitelist[6];`. This `2nd const` above informs the calling code that `some_function()` will not modify the array elements of `my_whitelist[]`.

```
  return some_function(my_whitelist, len);
}
```

---

Note: If  `my_whitelist[]` was a `const` array, its values cannot be *assigned* yet can be *initialized*.

```
// Example usage with a `const my_whitelist[]`
const address_t * const my_whitelist[] = { &addr1, &addr2, &addr3 };
```

---

Note: `address_t const *` is like `const address_t *`.  Leading with `const` matches the style of the C spec.

```
address_t const * const * my_addrs;
// same as 
const address_t * const * my_addrs;  // More common
```